# .Net Add-ons for Firefox?

Tags: .net, firefox, firefox-addon

Can we write some add-ons for Firefox with .Net Framework (C# or VB) ?

Comment: The question is "can we **write** addons", not asking if there are. In my opinion, this is a programming question, more suited to Stack Overflow. Voting to migrate there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot find any reference to .net and extensions as most firefox extensions work cross platform. (obviously there is Wine and Mono, but these are not perfect).

[I found this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension), which just says about using Visual Studio, but even that is using c++ and not any .net language.

It looks like you are pretty limited to [XUL (XML User Interface Language)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL).

Comment: Visual C++ uses C++ to interact with the .NET libraries

Comment: Well, I am no expert there - I am guessing then that IEtab and other Windows only extensions use c++ - .net must work then, but I certainly wouldn't know how to use it from c++!